# Is there a way i can include .deb package in Docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I created a `xyz.deb` package which, after installation, provides an application. I am trying to create a Docker container with `FROM ubuntu:20.04`.

How do I add my `xyz.deb` package in the `Dockerfile` and install it so that container comes ready with the application `xyz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) command in a Dockerfile lets you copy external files into the container. You can then install the .deb file as you would on your local system with a [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) command.

Simple example:

```
COPY ./xyz.deb /
RUN dpkg -i /xyz.deb
```

Comment: As per the COPY example xyz.deb file is in the current directory? and it will be copied to / ? also with escape the two lines will look like this?                                                            COPY ./xyz.deb / \
RUN dpkg -i /xyz.deb

Comment: xyz.deb in this case needs to be in the directory of your Dockerfile and it will be copied to / inside the image. The run command is a new layer inside the Dockerfile. There is no need to escape something. You can take a look in the Dockerfile Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: Why would you copy the file first?! A simple `RUN dpkg -i ./xyz.deb` would suffice!

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Did you test it? Can you really install debs directly from the host, without copying to the container first? That would be great, but I've never seen it otherwise.

Comment: @EricDuminil I thought it did, but I may be mistaken. The "./" syntax would be what is used to say "I want a local file" (opposed to a Docker environment file).